# CircuiTikZ — European NAND and NOR gates with american NOT-symbol

Tags: circuitikz

Is there a way to get something like this:

[image: European NAND as we use it]

…instead of this:

[image: Defaul CircuiTikZ NAND]

…using CircuiTikZ?

Answer (score 4):

There is the easy way:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\node[european and port] (A) {};
\node[circle,draw=black,fill=white,thick,inner sep=1pt] at ($(A.west)!0.93!(A.east)$) {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

You can also copy and modify the european and gate shape (and maybe fix the missing anchors).

Comment: It's a workaround, not a solution, but thank you.

Comment: In a recent version of `circuitikz` you can use `\ctikzset{tripoles/european not symbol=circle}` or `\ctikzset{tripoles/european not symbol=ieee circle}` (manual around page 118).